# WebView: Calling local JavaScript from remote HTML

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have an application which contains two WebView. One displays local HTML content and another one displays remote HTML content.

Is it possible for the remote HTML to access the local JavaScript? Any idea is welcomed. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first set webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

then you can access your functions like this:

webview.loadUrl("javascript:nameOfFunction()");